# git checkout causes modified file which cannot be added

Tags: git, clone, addition, commit, git-checkout

I `git clone` my repo and `git status` shows everything is fine (for want of a better expression) aka no changes, etc.

I then `git checkout` a feature branch and `git status` shows one file (which exists in both master and the feature branch) to be `modified`.

`git add .` does absolutely nothing to change the `git status` and I have not made any changes to the file during the process above.

The file is not git ignored.

**[UPDATE]**

I tried `git add <filename>` and the `git status` has changed from modified conflicted to modified modified, as represented by the posh git statuses:

```
modified conflicted +0 ~1 -0 !
modified modified +0 ~1 -0 ~
```

What I don't understand is how to resolve this. `git add .`, `git commit` and `git push --force` do nothing to the status.

Comment: Can you try doing this ? `git rm --cached -r .` and `git reset --hard`

Comment: This usually means one of two things: there's a case-folding issue (e.g., you're on Windows and whoever made the repo was on Linux and they made two files `A.TXT` and `a.txt`, and Linux can do that and Windows can't), or, there's a CRLF or other smudge issue where a file was committed in the wrong mode by someone who did not have the desired CRLF settings.

Comment: All the users involved are on Win7

Comment: @kedarnag-mukanahallipatna I tried both of those. Nothing has changed.

Comment: What does `git config core.autocrlf` say?

Comment: Sorry, I have discovered the issue before seeing your comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that one person had committed a file with the filename `NuGet.config` on master and another had committed the same file with the filename `NuGet.Config`. I have resolved the conflict on the remote repo browser and all is well.

Comment: So it *was* a case-folding issue, just not of the more typical form.

Comment: Yep - one to remember, for sure.