# "Changes not staged for commit" for a newly cloned project

Tags: git

I am simply a user of git and not an admin. I recently cloned a project into an empty directory. Once I clone it, I notice that there already are unstaged modification.

Here are the steps in the order that I execute.

1 - Create an empty directory

```
# mkdir /tmp/my-git-folder ; cd /tmp/my-git-folder
```

2 - Clone a project in the new EMPTY directory.

```
# git clone ssh://git@server.com:8011/foo/bar.git

Cloning into 'bar'...
remote: Counting objects: 32736, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9759/9759), done.
remote: Total 32736 (delta 20650), reused 31854 (delta 20171)
Receiving objects: 100% (32736/32736), 5.14 MiB | 815.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20650/20650), done.
```

Now this should be a fresh copy with no changes at all. But when I do a `git status` , this is the result.

3 - Check `git status`

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   some-folder/ansible-tasks.yml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

But I never made any changes what so ever. I tried to do a clean as well as a reset. But this change does not go away and I cannot have a clean copy.

```
# git checkout .
# git status

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   some-folder/ansible-tasks.yml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a") 

# git reset

Unstaged changes after reset:
M   some-folder/ansible-tasks.yml



# git clean -f
# git status

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   some-folder/ansible-tasks.yml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Any help would be appreciated since Im out of ideas as to what is wrong here.

Comment: could you compare `some-folder/ansible-tasks.yml` with the repository? at least, check whether its actually changed or not. also, do check whether your local repository actually checking out to the latest commit of your local current branch.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/52053462/1256452

Comment: @torek Such a coincidence that myself and the reporter of the other issue had the exact same problem i.e. case fondling. I deleted the other cased file from the repo and now all is well.

Comment: Ah, was it two-files-with-same-name-except-for-case? There are a lot of variants of this problem, so having that *particular* form is surprising enough. :-)

Comment: Yup. same file name with the first letter lower and upper case. That seemed to have caused the issue.